# MySQL backward and forward search history in command line

Tags: mysql, command-line

I can start backward history search in MySQL command line as I can do it in bash, e.g. with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. But unlike bash, I can't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to do forward history search once I'm in history search initiated with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>

I've turned of XON/XOFF, with `stty -ixon` in `~/.bashrc` so, I don't think that's the problem.

How do I use forward search when doing history search in command line MySQL command line? It is very important to move up and down through history with substring search in order to issue a previous command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `.inputrc` file in your home directory with the following contents

```
$if Mysql
"\C-s": forward-search-history
$endif
```

`~/.inputrc` is the initialization file for the `readline` library. It is usually not needed because all applications using `readline` come with default bindings which are enough for most users. `bash` includes `Ctrl-S` for `forward-search-history`, but `mysql` doesn’t. Putting a binding in `~/.inputrc` explicitly enables it for all applications. It is a good practice to use `$if ... $endif` to limit additions to the applications we are specifically interested in. Read [the manual](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) for more info.

Since `Ctrl-S` is used for other purposes in many terminal emulation environments, `stty -ixon` might be still needed in your case. To avoid XON/XOFF headaches, even if I’m aware that it is a bad practice to use nonstandard keybindings, I redefine `Ctrl-F` instead, because I need `forward-search-history` more than `forward-char`, which I have with the arrows anyway. I am **not** suggesting that you should do the same.